# Google site page in an iframe

Tags: apache-flex, iframe, google-sites, breakout

I'm building a quite large Flex application as our administration tools and I need build in documentation functionality. I want this documentation to be like a wiki and as we're using Google apps I though I'd use Google sites to host the wiki pages (why reinvet the weel...).

To include the wiki page in Flex I'm using the http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/ component that uses an iframe.

The problem is that it seem that google site uses some form of iframe javascript breakout script and that when i load the iframe the entire page is loaded with the wiki page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an anti-frame-busting script like the one on [Jeff's site](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001277.html).  Normally I wouldn't recommend that, but it seems like you have a legitimate need for it here.